# Grouped Boxplot on discrete x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a `dataframe` similar to the below:

```
df
variable   n        value
1   x_1 200 2.883524e+22
2   x_1 200 6.228677e+19
3   x_1 200 1.152941e+23
4   x_1 200 2.873297e+20
5   x_1 200 2.860104e+22
6  x_2 200 2.756752e+04
7  x_2 200 6.430455e+02
8  x_2 200 5.933116e+09
9  x_2 200 5.935287e+09
10  x_2 200 1.283504e+06
11  x_1 250 2.137800e+06
12  x_1 250 1.439365e+04
13  x_1 250 5.685357e+10
14  x_1 250 5.727160e+10
15  x_1 250 4.151983e+08
16  x_2 250 5.181344e+06
17  x_2 250 1.899797e+04
18  x_2 250 5.301975e+10
19  x_2 250 5.434231e+10
20  x_2 250 2.158825e+09
```

I am trying to develop a grouped box plot with `n` on the `x-axis`, `value` on the `y-axis` (using `scale_y_log10()`), and `variable` as the `fill` boxplots. However, I am struggling to actually plot each value of `n` on the `x_axis` and grouping the box plots. I currently have:

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = n, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(variable, 0.25))) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

but am struggling to get the results I was hoping for, is it possible to develop this type of box plot on a continuous `x-axis` and group by `variable`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got an error object model not found

Comment: @Rfanatic sorry, typo. I've updated the post.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly the problem, why should the X-axis be continuous? you can accomplish the result by coercing your  "n" variable as a factor variable

Comment: @AW27 do you need geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(n, 0.25)))

Comment: The `x-axis` doesn't have to be continuous, sorry, it's discrete. I was hoping to put three boxplots together for each value of `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the x axis discrete, simply feeding in the extra factor levels that you want to make the appropriate breaks in the x axis:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(n, levels = c(200, 250, 300)), y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = variable)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE, name = 'n')
```

[image]